# How to use SDWebImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, image, uitableview

I have `UITableViewCell` and in this load images, so I want to images load Asynchronies and show activate indicator. This time images loading time is very high and all images load after images show on table view. many times images cant load and user UIInterface is hang. and do not work any process in application.. I am very tired, I used a `SDWebImage` library. please help how it possible, Thank You

```
#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"

@interface pictureViewController ()
{
    NSArray*picarray;
    NSArray*titlearray;
    NSArray*idarray;
}

@end

@implementation pictureViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[[self navigationController] navigationBar] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]}];

    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background2.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    _tableview.separatorColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

    NSURLRequest *req=[[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://edutimeapp.com/toshow/chamber-of-commerc/ws/fetch_gallery.php"]];
    response =[[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:req delegate:self];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [response appendData:data];
    NSLog(@"error receving data %@",response);
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{

}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
     NSError *error;

     //NSLog(@"Error in receiving data %@",error);
     NSMutableDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves  error:&error];
     // NSLog(@"response data %@",json);

      NSArray *results = [json objectForKey:@"status"];
      picarray = [results valueForKey:@"img_url"];
      titlearray = [results valueForKey:@"title"];
      // NSLog(@"my title is%@",titlearray);
      idarray=[results valueForKey:@"id"];
      //NSLog(@"my galary id is%@",idarray);
      [self.tableview reloadData];
}


// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [picarray count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // NSLog(@"tableview cell");
    picture_viewcontrollerCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"htr"];
    if (cell==nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Cell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

     //NSData* imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: [picarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
    // UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
    //cell.picture.image =image;

    cell.titlelbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[titlearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    NSURL*url= [[picarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"img_url"];
    [cell.picture setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
    [cell.picture sd_setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Placeholder.jpg"]];


    return  cell;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try this (Show activityIndicator & Load Image using **SDWebImage**)-

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // NSLog(@"tableview cell");
    picture_viewcontrollerCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"htr"];
    if (cell==nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Cell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    cell.titlelbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[titlearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    NSURL*url= [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[picarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];

    [cell.picture setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];

    [cell.picture setShowActivityIndicatorView:YES];

    [cell.picture setIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];

    [cell.picture sd_setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeHolder.png"] options:indexPath.row == 0 ? SDWebImageRefreshCached : 0];

    return  cell;

}
```

Comment: '[<__NSCFString 0x7aff3ea0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key img_url.'

Comment: change this line- NSURL*url= [NSURL URLWithString: [[picarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"img_url"]]; with your previous line and check if this error exist or not.. check updated line in my code..

Comment: '[<__NSCFString 0x79f168a0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key img_url.'
same error show bellow

Comment: @A.Kumawat your picarray contains ImageURLs it does not contain dictionary object. So can get directly get imageUrl using indexPath.row. No Need to use valueForKey..

Comment: try my updated answer.. Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Its's working but this time click cell and  move another view. moving another  view time is very high? i want to click cell and move another view

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117292/discussion-between-dev-rk-and-a-kumawat).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your code can even compile? In your cellForRowAtIndexPath I see `[cell.picture sd_setImageWithURL:imageData placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Placeholder.jpg"]];`
 when you commented off your declaration of imageData.

Even if you didn't comment, this line should be

```
[cell.picture sd_setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Placeholder.jpg"]];
```

Comment: Sorry edit my code . please have a look again my question

Answer (score 0):

you have to use

```
NSURL*url= [[picarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"img_url"];
[cell.picture setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
[cell.picture sd_setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Placeholder.jpg"]];
```

instead of

```
NSURL*url= [[picarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"img_url"];
[cell.picture setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
[cell.picture sd_setImageWithURL:imageData placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Placeholder.jpg"]];
```

you have to pass url directly instead of imageData

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

1. Add `UIActivityIndicatorView` in tableview cell.
2. Changed following code in your `cellForRowAtIndexpath`.

   ```
   cell.activityIndicator.center = imageView.center;
   cell.activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
   NSURL *url= [[picarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"img_url"];
   [cell.picture sd_setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]
                         completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
                            [cell.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
                         }];
   [cell.picture addSubview:activityIndicator];
   [cell.activityIndicator startAnimating];
   ```

Comment: Declared in UITableViewCell class "activityIndicator"?

Comment: @A.Kumawat Yes add it in UITableViewCell.

Comment: last line [activityIndicator startAnimating]; no declared

Comment: I have one more issue, suppose I have not tableview only one image view on view controller. so how it Asynchronies image load.

Comment: For that you can pass that "imageview" insted of "cell.picture".

Comment: NSURL *url= [[picarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"img_url"];

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117306/discussion-between-ekta-makadiya-and-a-kumawat).